# Can fixedThreadPool have less threads than it was assigned to?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I have `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(/* nThreads= */ 2)` executor service. I noticed that sometimes when I pass TWO tasks to the executor service, it runs only ONE task, while I expect it to run TWO tasks. Is that possible and why?

I have two tasks which communicate with each other. These two tasks are put inside fixed thread pool of size two because I want both tasks to be running at the same time.

Comment: How do these tasks "communicate"?

Comment: Tasks communicate through some shared data structure.

Comment: *Show*. It sounds pretty likely that your "shared data structure" is causing synchronization between the two threads.

Answer (score 0):

Executors make sure you will reuse the thread poll most efficiently. But it doesn't gurantee all tasks are executed all at once. I am wondering if you can use 2 threads coming from 2 threadpool which only having 1 thread?

Comment: So do you suggest that it *is* possible that fixedthreadpool with 2 threads can run only one task while I submitted two tasks, right?

Comment: No. I am sure your 2 tasks will be run sooner or later. But as you said, you need both tasks run at the same time. Then you need tricky thing.

Comment: Oh I see. But what can be a reason why second task runs later? Is it because CPU busy or something?

Comment: Maybe. So for safy, you can create a thread pool having for example 5 threads. Thus your 2 tasks have be 99.9% possibility started at the same time. Much larger than your current 2 threads pool. by the way, [here](https://www.callicoder.com/java-executor-service-and-thread-pool-tutorial/) is good example.